# Git client that visualises branches for Linux

Tags: linux, software-development, git

I really like [GitUp](https://github.com/git-up/GitUp) on Mac, and I'm looking for something similar on Linux. Any recommendations for a tool that can visually show the branches in a project? To demonstrate what I mean, see this screenshot from the project's Readme:

[image: GitUp]
<sup>*GitUp*  viewing branches (click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy for adding the screenshot - it really shows well what I'd like. Branches as lines, branch names, labels, dots as commits, and not much else. Really minimal. No commit text or names or anything on the main display. It visualises the branches in a great way that really helps see what's been branched and where it merged, and which branches aren't yet merged. I know it's possible with the CLI but this view is superior for documents and presentations to a wider audience.

Comment: Gladly done – and even more glad you like it! And even more even more glad if that helps you to fitting recommendations now… Fingers crossed!

Answer (score 3):

If you want something *pretty* and yet professional and highly functional, you might want to check out [GitKraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). It is not open-source, but free for personal use.

Another one that is open-source is [GitAhead](https://gitahead.github.io/gitahead.com/), but I find it a bit more awkward to use, and not as fully-featured as GitKraken.

Comment: GitAhead looks interesting, but not available on Ubuntu 20.04 via Apt or Snap? Install via a shell script, with no clean way to uninstall is amateur at best, so I'll not risk it.

Comment: GitKraken looks good, but has a bad subscription model (pay yearly, but unlike Jetbrains for example has no right to use old version if no longer subscribing). I've no problem paying, but believe in software ownership not rental.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have them already installed without knowing it: `gitk` and `git-gui` are two graphical tools coming with the `git` packages on a Linux system.

[image] [image]
<sup>*GitK* (left) and *Git-GUI* (right) are two graphical tools for git on Linux (click images to enlarge)</sup>

- `gitk` gives you the branch visualization you've asked for
- `git-gui` helps you with commit, push & Co. From its "Branch" menu, you can directly open `gitk`

Comment: Solid answer, these are functional... but hardly in the same league of usability as GitUp. GitUp is just *so pretty*. I'm wanting the lines but without the masses of details.

Comment: Well, apologies – but I'm no Mac user, so how should I be able to tell? That's why we recommend giving all required details in your question (from the canned comments: »asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked.«), see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) :) May I suggest you edit your question and include your requirements verbatim?

Comment: I think the requirement of 'visualise branches a bit like GitUp' is about as clear as it can get. Still, these are useful suggestions and may help someone. Have an upvote :-)

Comment: Thanks @antonyh – and they may be clear to someone knowing GitUp. Non-Mac-users often do not. Maybe a screenshot would help. I've searched for where the GitUp project is, found it, and added link as well as screenshot for you.